# How to i make a login screen in vb.net and Access (VISUAL STUDIO 2015

Tags: database, vb.net, vb.net-2010

So I've used a tutorial on youtube on how to add a database and add things to the table, but now I want to use that data to for my login screen. 
http://tinypic.com/r/9bm7tf/9
http://tinypic.com/r/24fh99v/9

Right now I use this  code on the login button

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

        CheckLoginDetails()
        Dim Admin As Boolean = True

        If CheckLoginDetails() = 1 Then
            UserMenu.Show() ' I will make this form hide and open a new form.
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf CheckLoginDetails() = 2 Then
            AdminMenu.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("The login or password is incorrect, please try again.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function CheckLoginDetails() As Integer
        If TextBox1.Text = "login" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "password" Then
            Return 1
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "admin" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "password" Then
            Return 2
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: How does what you have not work?  `How to i make a login screen` is pretty broad, SO is for specific programming questions, not design consultation, tutoring or trolling for co-authors.  See [Ask]

Comment: because I want to use the data from the database "username" and password"

Comment: Then add code to open and read from the DB.  MSDN has oodles of sample code, even many *How To...* articles

Comment: I don't know how to ask the question

Comment: Typing `vb.net access database sample` into the magic Google answer machine gives this as the first hit: [How to use Microsoft Visual Basic .NET to connect to a Microsoft Access database and to retrieve data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821765)